# Can´t resolve React & SOCKET.IO CORS Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I trying to setup a very simple App to get familar with using SOCKET.IO in an React APP. Server looks like this:

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.origins('*:*');

io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.on('subscribeToTimer', (interval) => {
    console.log('client is subscribing to timer with interval ', interval);
    setInterval(() => {
      client.emit('timer', new Date());
    }, interval);
  });
});

const port = 8000;
io.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port ', port);
```

and React Client, which is setup with Create-React-App, looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:8000');


function subscribeToTimer(cb) {
  socket.on('timer', timestamp => cb(timestamp));
  socket.emit('subscribeToTimer', 1000);
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    subscribeToTimer((timestamp) => {
      this.setState({
        timestamp
      });
    });
  }

  state = {
    timestamp: 'no timestamp yet'
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Our awesome drawing app</h2>
        </div>
        This is the value of the timer timestamp: {this.state.timestamp}      
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

So basically server is sending a timestamp to the client using socket.io and this get´s then reflected there every second.
However this setup is running into the following CORS issue:

> localhost/:1 Failed to load
>   http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MEwUo-e:
>   Redirect from
>   'http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MEwUo-e'
>   to
>   'https://localhost:8443/socket.io/?eio=3&transport=polling&t=MEwUo-e'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I checked all the solutions provided here in other questions, i.e. `io.origins{*:*}`, I tried the same with using express.js and the cors npm package, etc. but the error remains. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? I am using Chrome Browser. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 24):

OK, I finally found the solution here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/641
which lead me to change on the code on the client side in line 4 to `const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:8000', , {transports: ['websocket']});`

Comment: openSocket('http://localhost:8000', {transports: ['websocket']})

Answer (score 8):

Use This :

```
const server = app.listen('3001', () => {
    console.log("Server Up")});

    const io = socket(server, {
        cors: {
            origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you add more explanation to your answer? What does your code do and how will it help the OP?

Comment: This code helps only in development. It would not work in production because origin won't be localhost in production.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem connecting to a WebSocket which always gives me CORS Error in network tab. @Sebs030 answer worked, fixed that issue by adding `transports` object to socket instance as follows.

```js
   const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
      transports: ['websocket'],
    });
```

ref: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/641

Answer (score 0):

My fix was simply to

> 1. update my NPM packages: socket-io (on the client, and the Node server).

```
npm update
```

I was using outdated and incompatible packages.

> 2. DO NOT FORGET to specify the allowed origins on the server

```
const server = app.listen('8002', () => {
console.log("Server Up")});

const io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000", //your own :port or a "*" for all origins
    }
});
```

});